# Count Number Of Occurence in 2D Array

Tags: python

Let's say I have an array like this

```
grid: 
    [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

I want to isolate the group of "items" in this case 1's which are three groups the rule being the 0's are used to separate them like intersections. So this example has 3 groups of 1.

If you know how to do this with python, the first question I'd be asked is what I've tried as proof of not handing my homework to the community, the idea I had was to iterate down and left  but that would have a high likelihood of missing some numbers since if you think about it, it would form a cross eminating from the top left and well this group is here to learn.
So for me and others who have an interest in this data science like problem be considerate.

Comment: connected components?

Comment: If you think of the 2D array like a grid, you can iterate over it like you read a book. Top-to-bottom, left-to-right. You can do this with 2 nested "for" loops.

Comment: @jodag in a sense yes, a connected group

Comment: There are various algorithms developed for this problem, most of which are relatively straightforward to implement. See [connected component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

Comment: @byxor knowing that the group you saw in the first line (2 numbers) is part of that in the second line is the tricky part. Plus now using that logic to know that group has been done and add to a total number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to know which sets are duplicates, you can use python's `set` built-in to determine unique items in a list. This can be a bit tricky since `set` doesn't work on a `list` of `list`s. However, you can convert this to a `list` of `tuple`s, put those back in a `list`, and then get the `len` of that list to find out how many unique value sets there are.

```
grid = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]

unique = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in grid)]

unique_count = len(unique)  # this will return 3
```

Comment: are cases like `[[1,1,1][1,0,1],[1,1,1]]` being ruled out? Or `[[1,1,0],[0,1,1]]`?

Comment: That would return a value of `2`.  Python's built-in `set` when used this way essentially removes all duplicate items from a list. since `[1,1,1]` is in that list twice, it removes one instance and only keeps the other.

Comment: But my understanding of the problem would be that OP wants it to return 1 since they are all "touching".

Comment: maybe i misunderstood what he is actually trying to do then. he wasn't very clear on what the end result was, so i was going off him saying "I want to isolate the group of 'items' [...] So this example has 3 groups of 1."

Comment: @samuel m can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Relatively straightforward depth first search based implementation of [connected component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling).

```
def get_components(grid, indicator=1):
    def label(g, row, col, group):
        if row >= 0 and col >= 0 and row < len(g) and col < len(g[row]) and g[row][col] == -1:
            # only label if currently unlabeled
            g[row][col] = group
            # attempt to label neighbors with same label
            label(g, row + 1, col, group)
            label(g, row, col + 1, group)
            label(g, row - 1, col, group)
            label(g, row, col - 1, group)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    # initialize label grid as -1 for entries that need labeled
    label_grid = [[-1 if gc == indicator else 0 for gc in gr] for gr in grid]
    group_count = 0
    for row, grid_row in enumerate(grid):
        for col in range(len(grid_row)):
            if label(label_grid, row, col, group_count + 1):
                group_count += 1
    return label_grid, group_count
```

The results of `label_grid, group_count = get_components(grid)` for your example inputs are

```
label_grid = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 3, 3]]
group_count = 3
```

And for cases like the following

```
grid = [[1 0 1],
        [1 1 1]]
```

we get `group_count = 1`.